# variables not printing in email form results

Tags: php, email, forms, variables

My form validates and submits fine, but the variables are not being printed in the emailed results.

Can anyone take a quick look at my processing file and tell me why this might be?

```
<?php

// CHANGE THE VARIABLES BELOW



$EmailFrom = $EmailFrom;
$EmailTo = "me@me.com";
$Subject = "Proposal Submission";


$FirstName = $HTTP_POST_VARS['FirstName'];
$LastName = $HTTP_POST_VARS['LastName']; 
$Title = $HTTP_POST_VARS['Title']; 
$Institution = $HTTP_POST_VARS['Institution']; 
$EmailFrom = $HTTP_POST_VARS['EmailFrom']; 
$Phone = $HTTP_POST_VARS['Phone']; 
$Address = $HTTP_POST_VARS['Address']; 
$City = $HTTP_POST_VARS['City']; 
$State = $HTTP_POST_VARS['State']; 
$Zip = $HTTP_POST_VARS['Zip']; 
$CoPresenter = $HTTP_POST_VARS['CoPresenter']; 
$ProgramTitle = $HTTP_POST_VARS['ProgramTitle']; 
$ProgramType = $HTTP_POST_VARS['ProgramType']; 
$ProgramDescription = $HTTP_POST_VARS['ProgramDescription']; 
$ProgramOutline = $HTTP_POST_VARS['ProgramOutline']; 
$ProgramTopic = $HTTP_POST_VARS['ProgramTopic']; 
$ProgramAudience = $HTTP_POST_VARS['ProgramAudience']; 
$ExpectedOutcome = $HTTP_POST_VARS['ExpectedOutcome']; 
$Experience = $HTTP_POST_VARS['Experience']; 
$AVEquipment = $HTTP_POST_VARS['AVEquipment']; 


// prepare email body text
$Body = "";
$Body .= "First Name: ";
$Body .= $FirstName;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Last Name: ";
$Body .= $LastName;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Title: ";
$Body .= $Title;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Institution: ";
$Body .= $Institution;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "EmailFrom: ";
$Body .= $EmailFrom;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Phone: ";
$Body .= $Phone;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Address: ";
$Body .= $Address;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "City: ";
$Body .= $City;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "State: ";
$Body .= $State;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Zip: ";
$Body .= $Zip;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "CoPresenter: ";
$Body .= $CoPresenter;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "ProgramTitle: ";
$Body .= $ProgramTitle;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "ProgramType: ";
$Body .= $ProgramType;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "ProgramDescription: ";
$Body .= $ProgramDescription;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "ProgramOutline: ";
$Body .= $ProgramOutline;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "ProgramTopic: ";
$Body .= $ProgramTopic;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "ProgramAudience: ";
$Body .= $ProgramAudience;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "ExpectedOutcome ";
$Body .= $ExpectedOutcome;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Experience: ";
$Body .= $Experience;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "AVEquipment: ";
$Body .= $AVEquipment;
$Body .= "\n";



// send email 
$success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, "From: <$EmailFrom>");

// redirect to success page
// CHANGE THE URL BELOW TO YOUR "THANK YOU" PAGE
if ($success){
  print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=contactthanks.html\">";
}
else{
  print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=error.html\">";
}
?
```

This is the form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Conference</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" >
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylesheet.css" type="text/css" media="screen" /> 

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/page.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


<script src="js/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/cmxforms.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


<script type= "text/javascript">

function changeInputs()
{
var els = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
var elsLen = els.length;
var i = 0;
for ( i=0;i<elsLen;i++ )
{
if ( els[i].getAttribute('type') )
{
if ( els[i].getAttribute('type') == "text" )
els[i].className = 'text';
else
els[i].className = 'button';
}
}
}

$().ready(function() {

    // validate signup form on keyup and submit
    $("#signupForm").validate({
        rules: {
            Firstname: "required",
            Lastname: "required",
            Institution: "required",            
            EmailFrom: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },

        },
        messages: {
            Firstname: "Please enter your first name",
            Lastname: "Please enter your last name",
            Institution: "Please enter an Institution name",            

            EmailFrom: "Please enter a valid email address"

        }
    });

});

</script>

<style type="text/css">
#signupForm {}
#signupForm label.error {
    margin-left: 5px;
    padding: 3px;
    width: auto;
    display: inline;
    color: #cc0000;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: #dedede;
}

.cmxform p
    {
    display: block;
    }

label
    {
    font: bold 14px/18px Arial;
    margin-top: 10px;
    }

label.small
    {
    font: 12px/18px Arial;
    margin-top: 5px;
    }

label,input.text,span
    {
    display: block;
    }

input.checkbox,.inline
    {
    display: inline
    }

input
    {
    margin-right: 5px;
    }

</style>


<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
<!-- Begin
function textCounter(field, countfield, maxlimit) {
if (field.value.length > maxlimit) // if too long...trim it!
field.value = field.value.substring(0, maxlimit);
// otherwise, update 'characters left' counter
else 
countfield.value = maxlimit - field.value.length;
}
// End -->
</script>

<?php
include ("google.inc");
?>

</head>

<body>

    <div id="wrapper"><!-- Begin wrapper -->

<?php
include ("header.inc");
?>      
        <hr />

        <div id="outer-space"><!-- Begin outer-space -->

            <div id="hfeed">

                <p id="page-info">Important Information</span>

                <div class="hentry">

                    <div class="entry-meta">
                        <abbr title="#">Conference date: 10/01/10</abbr>
                        <h2 class="entry-title"><a>Directions</a></h2>
                        <em>at</em> <span class="author vcard">Elgin Community College</span>
                    </div>

        <div class="entry-content">

<form name="myform" class="cmxform" id="signupForm" action="proposalengine.php" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
<fieldset>

<label for="FirstName">First Name</label>
<input id="FirstName" name="FirstName" />


<label for="LastName">Last Name</label>
<input id="LastName" name="LastName" />


<label for="Title">Title</label>
<input id="Title" name="Title" />


<label for="Institution">Institution: </label>
<input name="Institution" id="Institution" />


<label for="EmailFrom">Email: </label>
<input id="EmailFrom" name="EmailFrom" class="required email" />


<label for="Phone">Telephone: </label><input name="Phone" id="Phone" type="text" value="" size="10" maxlength="13" />


<label for="Address">Street Address: </label><input name="Address" id="Address" type="text" size="35" maxlength="75" />


<label for="City">City: </label><input name="City" id="City" />

<label class="inline" for="State">State: </label><select class="inline" name="State" id="State">
<option selected value="IL">IL</option>
    <option value="AL">AL</option>
    <option value="AK">AK</option>
    <option value="AZ">AZ</option>
    <option value="AR">AR</option>
    <option value="CA">CA</option>
    <option value="CO">CO</option>
    <option value="CT">CT</option>
    <option value="DE">DE</option>
    <option value="DC">DC</option>
    <option value="FL">FL</option>
    <option value="GA">GA</option>
    <option value="HI">HI</option>
    <option value="ID">ID</option>
    <option value="IN">IN</option>
    <option value="IA">IA</option>
    <option value="KS">KS</option>
    <option value="KY">KY</option>
    <option value="LA">LA</option>
    <option value="ME">ME</option>
    <option value="MD">MD</option>
    <option value="MA">MA</option>
    <option value="MI">MI</option>
    <option value="MN">MN</option>
    <option value="MS">MS</option>
    <option value="MO">MO</option>
    <option value="MT">MT</option>
    <option value="NE">NE</option>
    <option value="NV">NV</option>
    <option value="NH">NH</option>
    <option value="NJ">NJ</option>
    <option value="NM">NM</option>
    <option value="NY">NY</option>
    <option value="NC">NC</option>
    <option value="ND">ND</option>
    <option value="OH">OH</option>
    <option value="OK">OK</option>
    <option value="OR">OR</option>
    <option value="PA">PA</option>
    <option value="RI">RI</option>
    <option value="SC">SC</option>
    <option value="SD">SD</option>
    <option value="TN">TN</option>
    <option value="TX">TX</option>
    <option value="UT">UT</option>
    <option value="VT">VT</option>
    <option value="VA">VA</option>
    <option value="WA">WA</option>
    <option value="WV">WV</option>
    <option value="WI">WI</option>
    <option value="WY">WY</option>
</select>
<label class="inline" for="Zip">Zip Code: </label><input class="inline" name="Zip" id="Zip" type="text" value="" size="5" maxlength="10"  />

<label for="CoPresenter">Co-Presenter(s):</label>
<input type="text" name="CoPresenter" id="CoPresenter" class="required" />



<label for="ProgramTitle">Program Title:</label>
<font size="1" face="arial, helvetica, sans-serif"> ( You may enter up to 125 characters. )</font><br>
                <textarea name="message1" id="ProgramTitle" class="required" wrap="physical" rows="10" cols="35" onKeyDown="textCounter(this.form.message1,this.form.remLen,125);" onKeyUp="textCounter(this.form.message1,this.form.remLen,125);"></textarea>
    <br>

<label for="ProgramType">Program Type:</label>
                <span><input type="checkbox" name="ProgramType" value="ConcurrentSession" />Concurrent Session
                <span><input type="checkbox" name="ProgramType" value="RoundtableDiscussion" />Roundtable Discussion
                <span><input type="checkbox" name="ProgramType" value="InstitutionalInitiativeSession" />Institutional Initiative Session



<label for="ProgramDescription">Program Description:</label></td>
<font size="1" face="arial, helvetica, sans-serif"> ( You may enter up to 600 characters. )</font><br>
                <textarea name="message2" id="ProgramDescription" class="required" wrap="physical" rows="10" cols="35" onKeyDown="textCounter(this.form.message2,this.form.remLen,600);" onKeyUp="textCounter(this.form.message2,this.form.remLen,600);"></textarea>
    <br>


<label for="ProgramOutline">Program Outline:</label></td>
                    <font size="1" face="arial, helvetica, sans-serif"> ( You may enter up to 1800 characters. )</font><br>
                <textarea name="message3" id="ProgramOutline" class="required" wrap="physical" rows="10" cols="35" onKeyDown="textCounter(this.form.message3,this.form.remLen,1800);" onKeyUp="textCounter(this.form.message3,this.form.remLen,1800);"></textarea>
    <br>



<label for="ProgramTopic">Program Topic:</label>
                <span><input type="checkbox" name="ProgramTopic" value="Common Reading" />Common Reading</span>
                <span><input type="checkbox" name="ProgramTopic" value="Diversity" />Diversity</span>
                <span><input type="checkbox" name="ProgramTopic" value="Nontraditional Students" />Nontraditional Students</span>
                <span><input type="checkbox" name="ProgramTopic" value="Retention" />Retention</span>
                <span><input type="checkbox" name="ProgramTopic" value="Technology" />Technology</span>
                <span><input type="checkbox" name="ProgramTopic" value="Transfer Students" />Transfer Students</span>
                <span><input type="checkbox" name="ProgramTopic" value="Co-curricular programs and activities" />Co-curricular programs and activities</span>
                <span><input type="checkbox" name="ProgramTopic" value="Assessment/Outcomes" />Assessment/Outcomes</span>
                <span><input type="checkbox" name="ProgramTopic" value="Family Members/Parents" />Family Members/Parents</span>
                <span><input type="checkbox" name="ProgramTopic" value="Personal Development" />Personal Development</span>
                <span><input type="checkbox" name="ProgramTopic" value="Research" />Research</span>
                <span><input type="checkbox" name="ProgramTopic" value="Special Populations" />Special Populations</span>
                <span><input type="checkbox" name="ProgramTopic" value="Staff & training for first-year programs/services" />Staff & training for first-year programs/services</span>
                <span><input type="checkbox" name="ProgramTopic" value="Transition" />Transition</span>



<label for="ProgramAudience">Intended Audience:</label>
                <span><input type="checkbox" name="ProgramAudience" value="AcademicAffairsFaculty" />Academic Affairs/Faculty</span>
                <span><input type="checkbox" name="ProgramAudience" value="StudentAffairsDevelopment" />Student Affairs/Development</span>
                <span><input type="checkbox" name="ProgramAudience" value="CommunityCollege" />Community College/2-Year Institutions</span>
                <span><input type="checkbox" name="ProgramAudience" value="GraduateStudents" />Graduate Students</span>
                <span><input type="checkbox" name="ProgramAudience" value="FourYearPublic" />Four-Year Public Institutions</span>
                <span><input type="checkbox" name="ProgramAudience" value="FourYearPrivate" />Four-Year Private Institutions</span>



<label for="ExpectedOutcome">Expected Learning Outcomes:</label>
                <label class="small">List 1-2 expected learning outcomes below. (As a result of attending this session, participants will...)</font></label>
                    <font size="1" face="arial, helvetica, sans-serif"> ( You may enter up to 400 characters. )<br>
                <textarea name="message4" id="ExpectedOutcome" class="required" wrap="physical" rows="10" cols="35" onKeyDown="textCounter(this.form.message4,this.form.remLen,400);" onKeyUp="textCounter(this.form.message4,this.form.remLen,400);"></textarea>
    <br>



<label for="Experience">Experience:</label>
                <label class="small">List below any experiences you have related to your topic.</font></label>
                    <font size="1" face="arial, helvetica, sans-serif"> ( You may enter up to 125 characters. )<br>
                <textarea name="message5" id="Experience" class="required" wrap="physical" rows="10" cols="35" onKeyDown="textCounter(this.form.message5,this.form.remLen,600);" onKeyUp="textCounter(this.form.message5,this.form.remLen,600);"></textarea>
    <br>



<label for="AVEquipment">Audio/Visual Equipment</label>
                <label class="small">List any audio/visual equipment that you will need for this presentation.</label>
    <font size="1" face="arial, helvetica, sans-serif"> ( You may enter up to 125 characters. )</font><br>
                <textarea name="message6" id="AVEquipment" class="required" wrap="physical" rows="10" cols="35" onKeyDown="textCounter(this.form.message6,this.form.remLen,600);" onKeyUp="textCounter(this.form.message6,this.form.remLen,600);"></textarea>
    <br>

</fieldset>


<input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" onsubmit="return check();"/>
<input type="Reset" value="Clear" />

</FORM>         

        </div><!-- end entry content -->

                <div class="separator"></div>


<?php
include ("pagenav.inc");
?>              
            </div>

            <hr />


        </div><!-- End outer-space -->

        <hr />

<?php
include ("leftside.inc");
?>
<!-- this is actually the left sidebar -->

        <hr />

    </div><!-- End wrapper -->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `HTTP_POST_VARS` is deprecated. Use `$_POST` instead. I've never heard of `enctype="text/plain"` can you try removing that? After that, does echoing  `$Body`  output anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To help with debugging, you can use error_log and print_r:

```
error_log(print_r($HTTP_POST_VARS, true), 3, 'error.log');
error_log("Body = $Body\n", 3, 'error.log');
```

This will provide a dump of HTTP_POST_VARS as well as the final value of the Body variable (to make sure they are what you think they are.

Just an FYI, you should use the system superglobal $_POST instead of $HTTP_POST_VARS to get form data.

Also, make sure to consult the [runtime configuration of e-mail in PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php) so that you make sure that you can send mail successfully in the first place from the machine running the script.